# How to evaluate sums like this $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac {1} {4^{2^{i}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I thought about:

-Transform in a product of two sums and use Cauchy product.

-Complete this series into the geometric series.

The second one seems more likely to work, but I keep counting stuff more than 1 time

$ \frac S 4 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac {1} {4^{2^{i+1}}} $
$ S + \frac S 4 $ has a few numbers in commom but when you try to repeat the process ad infinitum gets quite hard to see which terms I need to take of in order for the series transform in the geometric.

Comment: If what you're looking for is a numerical approximation, that series converges very rapidly, a small number of terms will give you a very good approximation. If what you're looking for is a closed form, fuggedaboudid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known closed form for $($other$)$ series such as the one you just posted, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^{b^i}$, nor for this one in particular. Not unless $\Big\{|a|,|b|\Big\}\cap\big\{0,1\big\}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: If this is correct then you may want to at least give [a good approximation of it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\sum_{i%3D0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{2^i}}).

Comment: $S=0.3164215090218931437080797375305252217\ldots$, see [OEIS A$078585$](http://oeis.org/A078585).

Comment: to be dead honest a proof that it has not a closed form would be more interesting than the value in this case

Comment: @onlyme: I didn't say that such a proof exists, merely that humanity has not yet been able to find a closed form for these sums.

Comment: If the value of the series $\;S\;$ as written above by Lucian is accurate (and I think it is), with only $\;5\;$ summands I get an approximation of the order $\;10^{-18}\;$, which points towards the truth of Gerry's comment below the question.